# how to set never expire Customer token in Magento 2.4?

Tags: customer, magento2.4, token

In magento 2.4, there is a field in `System > Configuration > Service > Oath > Customer Token Lifetime (hours)`. This field is Mandatory field,I wanna set this one never expires, Anyone know how can I set so customer token never expires ?
Any Hint ? Any Method need to override ?

Answer (score 0):

This field is **not mandatory** on M2.4.3.

When save as **empty** it will disable and you can generate a token that **never expires**.

[image]

Comment: I have magento 2.4.0